# get type in php returns "object" and not the object type

Tags: php

im trying to get the type of the object that i receive in the constructor using `gettype($this->object)` .
but im only getting "object" my constructor:     p

```
public function __construct($object=null)
    {
        $this->object=$object;

    }
```

the object that i send to class:

```
$campaign = new Campaign();

$type = new Nodes\CampaignDatabaseNode($campaign);
$type->checkType();
```

the checkType(); only echo the type of the object

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just to explain why [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) doesn't work as expected since others have already provided the correct answer. `gettype()` returns the type of *variable* — i.e. boolean, integer, double, string, array, object, resource, NULL or unknown type (cf. the `gettype()` manual link above).

In your case the variable `$campaign` is an object (as returned by `gettype()`), and that object is an instance of the class Campaign (as returned by `get_class()`).

Comment: I never really understood that in PHP. `$campaign` is an instance of class Campaign, I get that. However, it sounds logical to me that `$campaign` is of type Campaign too.

Especially since we can do that: `function test(int $integer, Campaign $campaign)`.

In my function signature, I precise what type I want, not what instance of class I want.

Comment: The ability to restrict parameters by class "type" is newer than the `gettype()` function. PHP is generally very conservative about introducing breaking changes to old functions. If you look at the documentation for `gettype`, the ONLY modification they've made since it's inception in PHP 4 is a tweak to how closed resources are identified (in 7.2.0).

Answer (score 16):

You can use `get_class($object);`

http://www.php.net/get_class

To help with your new situation (if I've understood properly)

```
<?php

namespace Ridiculous\Test\Whatever;

class example {}

$example = new example();

echo get_class($example) . '<br>';
echo basename(get_class($example)); // this may be what you're after
```

Comment: i tried to use get_class but its return me the all path to the class.

Answer (score 10):

```
gettype($obj);// Output: "object"
$obj instanceof Myclass;// Output: true (if it's an instance of that class)
```

`gettype()` returns the type of variable, like "string", "integer", "array", etc.

`instanceof` checks whether object is instance of that specified class.

Answer (score 1):

1 In order to get the type of the object, use the function `get_class()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php .

2 In order to prevent invalid object passing, you can typehint the argument class, like the following:

```
public function __construct(Campaign $object=null)
{
    $this->object=$object;
}
```

Comment: 1. i tried to use get_class but its return me the all path to the class.
2. its not only for this type of object.