# how to recive a class name in laravel in blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a variable called action in my blade and the `dd` of it is like below:

```
TCG\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction {#2273 ▼
  #dataType: TCG\Voyager\Models\DataType {#513 ▶}
  #data: TCG\Voyager\Models\User {#218 ▶}
}
```

Now what I want to do is to retrieve the `TCG\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction` from it and do some `if` on it but I cant get the key of that.
So what I have tried is like below but I had no luck with that:

```
@if($action === 'TCG\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction')
```

Can you please tell me how can get that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get type in php return "object" and not the object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651380/get-type-in-php-return-object-and-not-the-object-type)

Comment: `get_class($action)` ? you want this ?

Comment: Consult the second answer in the linked duplicate (it answers what you need more straightforwardly than the accepted one).

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes exactly u can answer it i mark is as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get_class($action)` to get class `TCG\Voyager\Actions\DeleteAction`

ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php